# Array of bytes in Python (not bytearray object)

Tags: python-3.x, byte, mac-address

I have this MAC address in this format:
15302363377678 
(or 0xdeadbeef00e in hex)
How can I represent it as an array of bytes in Python? Here I want it in decimal form.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)? It returns *an array of bytes representing an integer*.

```py
mac_address = (15302363377678).to_bytes(length=8, byteorder="big")
print(mac_address)
print(*mac_address)
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x00\r\xea\xdb\xee\xf0\x0e'
0 0 13 234 219 238 240 14
```